# Scroll bar in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, scroll

I can't find way to scroll in WP7. I have more blocks outside the emulator screen but I can't scroll it. any ideas? I am newbie in visual, just trying to learn, so please explain where should I copy code :)

```
    x:Class="Fitness_excercises.MainPage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
        FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
        Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
        shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="976" Width="480">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="904*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Fitness excercises" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,52,12,-3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Button Content="Weider's six" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="-12,52,46,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Waist Slimming Exercises" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,104,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Leg excercises" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,157,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Buttocks excercises" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,209,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Hand and wrist excercises" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,262,0,0" Name="button5" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Warm-up" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,0,0,0" Name="button6" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="100 push-ups" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-13,576,0,0" Name="button7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="300 crunches" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,367,0,0" Name="button8" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Aerobic training" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,418,0,0" Name="button9" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="50 pull-ups" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,469,0,0" Name="button10" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="300 squats" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,524,0,0" Name="button11" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Chest excercises" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-12,313,0,0" Name="button13" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Diet atlas" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-13,629,0,0" Name="button12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="82" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="-13,693,0,0" Name="button14" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" />
        <ScrollViewer Height="716" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="456,0,0,0" Name="ScrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0" />

    </Grid>
</Grid>

<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which part of the interface are you wanting to have scroll? Whichever part that is, you should surround that element with a `<ScrollViewer>`.

For example, if you're wanting to have the ContentPanel Grid scroll, you would do something like this:

```
 <ScrollViewer 
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Margin="12,52,12,-3" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    ....
    </Grid> 
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Ok, but when i release mouse button it comes back to normal. I have buttons away from screen, and when i want to click on it I can't because it comes back

Comment: Could you maybe rephrase? I'm not quite sure what problem you're having or what you mean by "I have buttons away from screen"

Comment: In visual i see on my phone screen 16 buttons, the next 3 are away from screen (under these 16,but not visible), I have to move up content panel to see them. In emulator when I scroll down (holding mouse button) i see next 3 buttons,but when i release, it comes back to these main 16. Is it possible to lock view ? I mean, when i scroll it stays in position i scrolled.

Comment: It sounds like those buttons aren't inside the `ScrollViewer`. Also, I noticed that you have an additional `ScrollViewer` within your `ContentPanel` `Grid`. You should probably remove that.

Comment: Noo...All buttons are inside scroll viewer. Look, when you scroll page on the internet, you scroll and it stays in position you scrolled, yes? In emulator when i scroll from one position to the second position and when i release button it comes back to first position. I would like it stay on the second position (there,where i   scrolled)